# php laravel error with database data insertion

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am new to  PHP Laravel. I create a table using PHP artisan migrate.Using PHP artisan tinker command i try to insert the data to  database .but it gives the following error.what is the reason for this.

```
DB::table('users')
->insert(['id'=>'1','name'=>'admin','email'=>'mihiran.chathuranga@gmail.com','remember_token'=>'1','created_at'=>' ','updated_at' => ' ']);
```

error message:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: ' ' for column 'created_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (1, admin, mihiran.chathuranga@gmail.com, 1,  ,  ))'
```

Comment: Read the error message. `Incorrect datetime value: ' ' for column 'created_at'`. You're trying to insert a space into a date time field.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert `'created_at'=>' '`, try using

`'created_at'=> (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

and it should insert for you.